# Change UUID of Android Device

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb

I'm trying to change bulk devices UUIDs using DroidExplorer I've opened `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` selected android_id from table secure to change the value. I then click Write changes however it's not taking the changes even after the reboot the device still reverts to the old UUID of the device. What am I missing and is there a better solution?

The devices are running on Android Kitkat 4.4.2 and they're Chinese tablets.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to manage that it using SQL command.

1. Go to /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
2. Open the database using SQL Database Editor
3. Use SQL Command

   UPDATE android_id
   SET value = REPLACE(value, 'old-id', 'new-id')
   WHERE _id <=25
4. Click File > Write Changes
5. Exit and Push changes to device

You're done!